# Nautilus, gedit etc - remeber windows position

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, gedit

How to force nautilus and gedit (and practically all program's windows on ubuntu) to always remember their window position? When i start another nautilus window, it is randomly placed on different positions of desktop. I dont wanna that. I work on 16:9 monitor, with one document window on left and nautilus/gedit on right, it really annoys me to reposition every time i start new window or run new instance of nautilus/gedit.

I use ubuntu 12.04.3 lts.

Comment: Ive red this topic, there are no answers to my questions. They answer how to preserve running applications. Im able to do it now, hibernation or sleep is well known function to me, but i want programs remember windows' size and positions, regardless of pc state (after hibernation/sleep/shut-down, or simply after quit and re-run this application).

Comment: There **are** answers to your question - you may not like them though :-)

Comment: I read through this topic one more time, but i dont see anything about nautilus, only firefox and another apps, or window-remembering function in general in some old bug reports (their status is something between undecided and "hello, i am 5 years old!"). But yeah, voices there are quite sceptical - so do i understand well, that this flawed behaviour is intended and will not change?